# Transaction integrity error during contact import

Tags: import

I've been importing contacts all day without problems then suddenly I started receiving this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame, referer: /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/import/contact&_qf_Preview_display=true&qfKey=ea8c9a3e9b606fb4932502f3dcc8f48d_7347 mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107, referer: /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/import/contact&_qf_Preview_display=true&qfKey=ea8c9a3e9b606fb4932502f3dcc8f48d_7347`

Running latest version of WordPress and CiviCRM in MySQL. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!